# Beams of different colors do not interfere with each other

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

Experimentally I know that two monocromatic beams of different colors or orthogonal polarizers do not interfere with each other (so the interference coefficient is zero). Theoretically, why does that happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also [Will overlapping two different beams of coherent light with different wavelength cause interference?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345155/will-overlapping-two-different-beams-of-coherent-light-with-different-wavelength)

Comment: And [Can only two equal EM-wavelength interfere? If so why is that?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/325977/can-only-two-equal-em-wavelength-interfere-if-so-why-is-that)